# Part of the command is not executed in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, playwright, npm-scripts, allure

I added to command this line

`ALLURE_RESULTS_DIR=allure-test`

Here is this piece of code

```
 if [[ "$has_specific_tests" == "true" ]]; then
  information_message "Starting specified tests"

  if [[ "$is_experiment" == "true" ]]; then
   ALLURE_RESULTS_DIR=allure-test npm test "$experiment" -- "$allure_index"
  fi
```

But the script runs without this part. I need to execute this command

```
ALLURE_RESULTS_DIR=allure-test npx playwright test "regression/experiment" "--reporter=line,allure-playwright"
```

But executed only this part of command

```
npx playwright test "regression/experiment" "--reporter=line,allure-playwright"
```

Terminal

```
leonid@lenovo:~/kameleoon/automated-tests$ bash scripts/run_tests.sh
<---- STARTING SPECIFIED TESTS ---->

> automated-tests@1.0.0 test
> npx playwright test "regression/experiment" "--reporter=line,allure-playwright"
```

My entire script

```
#!/bin/bash
CYAN='\033[0;36m'
NO_COLOR='\033[0m'

# Get environment variables
is_experiment=$REGRESSION_EXPERIMENT
is_login=$REGRESSION_LOGIN
is_personalization=$REGRESSION_PERSONALIZATION
is_project=$REGRESSION_PROJECT
is_smoke=$SMOKE
is_admin_access=$([[ $TEST_CREDENTIALS ]] && echo "true" || echo "false")

# Check if at least one specific test is configured
specific_tests=("$is_experiment" "$is_login" "$is_personalization" "$is_project" "$is_smoke" "$is_admin_access")
has_specific_tests=$([[ "${specific_tests[*]}" =~ "true" ]] && echo "true" || echo "false")

# Literal variables
tests_path="tests"
test_folders=$(cd $tests_path && ls)
experiment="regression/experiment"
login="regression/login"
personalization="regression/personalization"
project="regression/project"
smoke="smoke"
administrator_access="administratorAccess"
regression="regression"
ignored_tests=("$regression" "$smoke" "$administrator_access")
allure_index="--reporter=line,allure-playwright"

function information_message {
  echo -e "${CYAN}<---- ${1^^} ---->${NO_COLOR}"
}

function error_check {
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -e "${RED}<---- ${1^^} ---->${NO_COLOR}"
    exit 1
  fi
}

# clearing previous report
sh bin/clear-report.sh

function run_specific_tests {
  cd "${1}" || error_check "Couldn't open ${1} folder"
  tests=$(ls -1 | tr '\n' ' ')
  npm run test ${tests//[$'\n']/} -- "$allure_index"
  information_message "Finished ${1} tests"
  cd ..
}

function open_report {
  allure generate "${1}"allure-results -o "${1}"allure-report --clean && screen -d -m -S ALLURE allure open -p 8080 "${1}"allure-report
}

function run_all_tests {
  for folder in $test_folders; do
    if [[ ! ("${ignored_tests[*]}" =~ "$folder") ]]; then
      run_specific_tests "$folder"
    fi
  done
  open_report "../../"
}

# Go to test folder
cd "${tests_path}" || error_check "Couldn't open ${tests_path} folder"

# Run specific tests if configured
if [[ "$has_specific_tests" == "true" ]]; then
  information_message "Starting specified tests"

  if [[ "$is_experiment" == "true" ]]; then
   ALLURE_RESULTS_DIR=allure-test npm test "$experiment" -- "$allure_index"
  fi

  if [[ "$is_login" == "true" ]]; then
    npm test "$login" -- "$allure_index"
  fi

  if [[ "$is_personalization" == "true" ]]; then
    npm test "$personalization" -- "$allure_index"
  fi

  if [[ "$is_project" == "true" ]]; then
    npm test "$project" -- "$allure_index"
  fi

  if [[ "$is_smoke" == "true" ]]; then
    npm test "$smoke" -- "$allure_index"
  fi

  if [[ "$is_admin_access" == "true" ]]; then
    run_specific_tests "$administrator_access" -- "$allure_index"
  fi
  # Generate and open allure report
  open_report "../"

  # Otherwise run all the other tests
else
  information_message "Starting general tests"
  run_all_tests
fi
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I have added more information

Comment: Still not clear. How do you know the npx command executed with or without the value of that variable?

Comment: I see in the terminal  bash scripts/run_tests.sh
<---- STARTING SPECIFIED TESTS ---->

> automated-tests@1.0.0 test
> npx playwright test "regression/experiment" "--reporter=line,allure-playwright"

Comment: and allure-test folder is not created

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the shell does with `var=value command arg ...` -- read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Executing-Commands => "the variables are added to the environment of the executed command"

Comment: ALLURE_RESULTS_DIR=allure-test npx playwright test "regression/experiment" "--reporter=line,allure-playwright"

Comment: Right: the variable is in the _environment_ for the `npm test` command -- it's not actually part of the command. You'll need to see what `npx playwright test` does with the ALLURE_RESULTS_DIR **environment variable**.